How do I replace the mini cart icon with text 'My Cart'
My magento theme doesnt display the minicart icon, I suppose that it is messed up some where with the fontawsome, now i want to change it from using icon to just plain text 'My Cart'. I'm using solwind freego theme.


Add below CSS in your custom less file.
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart .text {
     &:extend(.abs-visually-hidden-reset all);
 }
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart:before,
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart.active:before {
    display: none;
}


You can achieve this by overriding the CSS. The CSS below can hide the icon and display the text. Please add this in "Admin > Content > Configuration > MyStoreView > HTML Head > Scripts and Style Sheets" to test it directly.
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart span.text {position:relative;}
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart:before {display:none;}


